# Connect to local client from server-side Blazor App

Tags: c#, websocket, localhost, blazor, blazor-server-side

I‘m currently transforming an C# Desktop Application to a server-side Blazor App. But at some point we need to access local ressources of the client (e.g. Printers and specific Files). For this usecase I thought about writing a little Windows Service that listens on a localhost Port on the client for WebSocket connections. I then want my Blazor App to connect to this WebSocket to query specific information from the Service and it‘s local client.

Is this a good concept to enable some sort of local access for Blazor Apps? I just want some specialized access with little overhead, nothing like Electron in this case. I can‘t find some best practises for this usecase in Blazor so far.

If it‘s a good concept, then how can I make the server-side Blazor App to connect to a clients localhost Port? Because most of the code is running server-side - What‘s the best way ro connect to the localhost from within my App?

Thanks, Joshua

Comment: If you don't mind experimenting a little, you could try .net 6 & MAUI to host a web browser control & your blazor app. eg like electron, but using .net & native components rather than an entire chromium install.

Comment: Personally I would replace printing and file access features with something more web friendly. eg downloading pdf's, storing files in the cloud.

Comment: Well, the point of a server is that it will serve the files to a browser.  You aren't SUPPOSED to be able to access local files in that context.  I mean-- if this is a local file and you want to print, why aren't you just using the OS Print capabilities?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 You're right, I'm generally not supposed to access local files in this context - But why not make local functionality possible for users that do want this? In some usecases (auto printing of shipping labels on specific printers and paper trays) a regular PDF file and the browser printer dialog is simply not enough. And also with electron or .NET 6 & MAUI the printing capabilities are very limited and tinkering.

Comment: Well, you're talking about using a browser.  Microsoft can't really control how Chrome (for example) interacts with the operating system.  Probably your best bet is to make a desktop app with an embedded browser that adds extended functionality (maybe by using a custom user agent string and catching that in javascript to reveal extra controls).